# Why my local javascript code is not being run on a local HTML 5 file?

Tags: javascript

The code is fully copied below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Avaliações</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2-min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xslt.js" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('123');
        $(function(){
            alert('affe');
            $('body').xslt({xmlUrl: 'xxx.xml', xslUrl: 'xxx.xsl'});
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why don't even the alerts work?

edit2: Nevermind, it was a typing error on my side when including jQuery... I realized it was something like this when the XLST plugin warned me about undefined jQuery and $.

Comment: Have you checked the error console?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the error console, I've even installed Firebug, nothing was reported, oddly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because using " /> " doesn't work for javascript. Unfortunately, you need to put

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2-min.js"></script>
```

for both your javascript files

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure `<script>` tags cannot use short form syntax. So

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2-min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xslt.js" />
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xslt.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, that's it, all the remaining code just get nested within first not closed script ;)